# Rails - form_for remote true - ajax before

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have simple form with remote true

```
<% form_for @search,:url => some_path, remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :some_field %>
  <%= f.button 'click' %>
<% end %>
```

And next I add will_paginate with endless scroll for results of this form.

The problem in my case is a parameter, which is not passed on to subsequent pages after submit forms. So I'm trying to save the parameters in the session, but I can not clear the session after re-submit forms.

How can I make some ajax when user click on button in this form - but before submiting form? :) Is it possible?

EDIT

Ok i made form without remote => true , and with $.when ...done() ajax and prevent default behavior for form. I don't find any solution for remote => true and wait with submit until other ajax are finished.